# Not all urls opening aws pages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, godaddy-api

I deployed my website on aws. I have added the certificate to my godaddy domain so that pages gets redirected to website. But wherever I have directory its not opening. For example:

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

[www.example.com/index.html](http://www.example.com/index.html)

above 2 links opening with no issues.

but
[www.example.com/abc/index.html](http://www.example.com/abc/index.html)

This is not opening. But its opening with AWS elasticbeanstalk link.

Can you please help

Comment: Could you provide more information? How is your DNS configuration set up? How is your ssl set up? How is your infrastructure in aws set up (Ec2, alb etc).

Comment: My site is www.rankbazaar.com/index.html . If you go to https://www.rankbazaar.com/sports/news-201809142003240002-James-Foster-bids-adieu-to-Essex.html this is not working. But when you go to http://rb-env.eba-qmrq7pid.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com//sports/news-201809142003240002-James-Foster-bids-adieu-to-Essex.html its not working

Comment: I added SSL/TLS certificate in AWS. I added CNAME in my GO Daddy Manage DNS. While adding certificate I gave *.ranbazaar.com. Then added these cname settings to my DNS. Infrastructure is EC2

Comment: What is the double forward slash in the elb url for? Could that suggest some broken configuration somewhere? You wouldn't usually see that in url. Do you run something like nginx, apache2 or similar? Have you configured the host etc there?

Comment: Also, what does your cname look like?

Comment: You can remove double url. Thats fine. I am running on tomcat. http://rb-env.eba-qmrq7pid.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/sports/news-201809142003240002-James-Foster-bids-adieu-to-Essex.html

Comment: It appears to work without ssl so I'd suggest you may have some incorrectly configured settings on tomcat. You'd normally need to set your ssl config in tomcat I think. I've never personally used it though.

Comment: It would appear there's something that needs setting up there like a connector or something?

Comment: https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm step 2 here says something. I'm not sure if that's correct or not but may be worth checking.

Comment: But nothing working for now